# SCSS/Modernizr chained classes

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, modernizr

I'm not shure this can be done. But consider following, i'm using modernizr and trying to make css buttons based on classes from parents.

I've made a JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/qBkPL/1/

My desired outcome is:

```
.foo.bar .selector
```

But, the outcome when scoping to parent:

```
.foo .selector.bar
```

Comment: Put it in the question, i'll remove my comment(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply can't do it that way.  To get your desired output, you must write it like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/qBkPL/2/

```
a.parent-chaining {
    .foo.bar & {
        color:red; // this should be red
    }
}
```

Nesting selectors is not a requirement, use it when it makes sense to do so.